# Function that would get minimum, maximum and average in c

Tags: c, loops, max, min, function-definition

Hello I wrote a  function that continuously accepts integer inputs from the user until the user enters -999 (sentinel value).  The function also identifies the highest and lowest value entered, the average of  inputs. I already wrote a code for it but I can't seem to get the correct average value for it and need help revising it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getMinMaxAve ( int *min, int *max, float *ave)
{
    int nVal;
    int nMin = 0;
    int nMax = 0;
    int nResult = 1;
    int nCount = 0;

    while (nVal != -999)
{
    printf ("Value:");
    scanf ("%d", &nVal);
    
    if (nVal !=-999) 
    {
        if (nVal > nMax)
            nMax = nVal;
        if (nVal < nMin)
            nMin = nVal;
        nResult += nVal;
        nCount += 1;
        
    }
}
        *min = nMin;
        *max = nMax;
        *ave = nResult / nCount;
}


int main ()
{
        int nMin;
        int nMax;
        int nResult;
        float fAve;

        nResult = getMinMaxAve (&nMin, &nMax, &fAve);

if (nMin == -999)
{
    printf ("Min: NA\n");
    printf ("Max: NA\n");
    printf ("Average: NA\n");
}
else 
{
    printf ("Min: %d\n", nMin);
    printf ("Max: %d\n", nMax);
    printf ("Average: %f\n", fAve);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_I can't seem to get the correct average value for it_" <- not a problem description. Show what input you give the program, what output you get, and what output you expect instead.

Comment: What happens when the input stream contains "foo"?  You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  Always.

Comment: @Marty Mcfly Why is this variable int nResult = 1; initialized by 1?!

Comment: What is `nResult` - your function doesn't return anything. You also don't use this return value.

Comment: Integer division cannot produce a `float` value. Please cast one operand `*ave = (float)nResult / nCount;`

Comment: `nMin` and `nMax` shouldn't be initialized to 0. If you have only negative numbers, the `nMax` value will be wrong. If you have strictly positive numbers, the `nMin` value will be wrong too

Comment: `#include <limits.h> ` and `int nMin  = INT_MAX; int nMax = INT_MIN;`

Comment: `nVal` is not initialised when first read (in the loop condition), causing undefined behaviour. This should be the end of the discussion. It is not even guaranteed to have a cleanly written value when used the second time (in the if condition).

Comment: Please compile your code using a basic set of compilation flags to catch simple errors. See your compiler's documentation (e.g. for [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), you may use `gcc -Wall -Werror`).

Answer (score 1):

For starters the program has undefined behavior because the function `getMinMaxAve` that is declared like

```
int `getMinMaxAve` ( int *min, int *max, float *ave)
```

returns nothing.

It is better to return from the function the number of entered values.

It is unclear why the variable `nResult` is initialized by 1 and not by 0.

```
int nResult = 1;
```

Setting the variables `nMin` and `nMax` to the value o

```
int nMin = 0;
int nMax = 0;
```

can produce an incorrect result for minimum and maximum values.

Also in general the variable `nCount` can be equal to 0 if the user will not enter an actual number. In this case this statement

```
*ave = nResult / nCount;
```

also invokes undefined behavior. And moreover in this expression `nResult / nCount` there is used the integer arithmetic.

This if statement in main

```
if (nMin == -999)
```

does not make a sense.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t getMinMaxAve ( int *min, int *max, double *ave )
{
    const int Sentinel = -999;
    
    size_t count = 0;
    double total = 0;

    for ( int value; scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 && value != Sentinel; ++count )
    {
        if ( count == 0 || value < *min ) *min = value;
        if ( count == 0 || *max < value ) *max = value;
        total += value;
    }
    
    if ( count != 0 )
    {
        *ave = total / count;
    }
    
    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int nMin;
    int nMax;
    double fAve;
        
    if ( getMinMaxAve( &nMin, &nMax, &fAve ) )
    {
        printf ( "Min: %d\n", nMin );
        printf ( "Max: %d\n", nMax );
        printf ( "Average: %.2f\n", fAve );
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Min: NA\n");
        printf ("Max: NA\n");
        printf ("Average: NA\n");       
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -999
Min: 1
Max: 10
Average: 5.50
```

Comment: You over-markdowned the second occurence of "getMinMaxAve" and I miss discussion of the non-initialised `nVal`.

Answer (score 1):

First the variable you keep the sum in `nResult` is initialized at 1. That must absolutely be zero.

Second `*ave = nResult / nCount;` does integer division as both `nResult` and `nCount` are integers.

A way out of this is to declare `nResult` as `float`. Then that same expression actually does what you expect it to do. And better rename that variable to `totalSum`, or something equally informative.

(But you better use `double` instead of `float` everywhere)

There are more problems with your code, but I limit myself to just answer your question about the average.